# sweetalert pause execution and return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I'd like to replace [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) `confirm` with sweetalert, in the following code snippet, but I found two limitations, 1) sweetalert does not pause execution like confirm, 2) sweetalert does not return value, boolean, like confirm:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cancelList').click(function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();
    m = confirm($(this).attr('confirm-msg'));
    if (!m){
      return true;
    }
    url = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
......
```

For returning the Boolean value, I tried to use it like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cancelList').click(function(e){   
    e.preventDefault(); 
    m = false;
    swal({text:$(this).attr('confirm-msg'), type: 'warning',title: '', showCancelButton: true}, function(isConfirm){m = isConfirm; return m;});
    alert('It should not be here before decide in swal');
    if (!m){
      return true;
    }
```

In the above snippet, the `alert` is invoked before the sweetalert confirmation appearing!!! and the global variable `m` seems to be not affected by clicking on OK or Cancel on sweetalert.

What's the problem here? Is there any workaround rather than including the rest of code inside the callback function of sweetalert?

Comment: No, there is no other workaround other than including the rest of the code inside the callback function. (Well, you could use a Promise mechanism or something like that, but you cannot "pause" JavaScript.)

Comment: @Pointy but `alert` and `confirm` "pause" JavaScript, don't it?

Comment: Yes, `alert()` and `confirm()` do. They're browser features that behave that way, so if you like you can use those. There are no facilities for implementing something like that with your own code.

Comment: @Pointy well, but I am not able to understand how could a procedure, `alert`, is executed before the previous procedure, `swal`, is invoked?

Comment: Because the `alert` isn't executed before `swal`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli when I click on `#cancelList` the alert is invoked first, then the `swal` confirm message is appeared!

Comment: what i think is that may be swal has functions, code to execute that take more milliseconds (or parts of MS) to popup alert scene  than the normal alert has (0 MS). so they have callback.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found online that sweet alert uses promises. You can use sweet alert as:

```
Swal.fire({
    /*attributes*/
}).then(function (){
    /*code to execute after alert*/
});
```

This way the code in the promise block will be executed after clicking the alert button